# ReactJs: How to make root component rerender when a prop changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, mern

I have this component `NotificationToast` that manages notifications.
I need to be **always rendered** when the user is **authenticated**.

So this is what I did:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const state = store.getState();
    const { isAuthenticated } = state.auth;

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter basename="/">    
          <Switch>
            <PublicRoute path="/register-page" component={RegisterPage} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/profile-page" component={ProfilePage} />
            <Redirect to="/home" />
          </Switch>
          {isAuthenticated && (
            <div>
              <NotificationToast />
            </div>
          )}
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The problem is that this does not work in the **following scenario**:

1. The user has not logged-in.
2. So he is not authenticated. So `state.auth.isAuthenticated` is `false`
3. When he logs-in, `state.auth.isAuthenticated` gets set to `true`.
4. But, the problem is that `App` does not detect this change and so it does not get rerendered.
5. And so, `NotificationToast` does not get rendered.
6. And so the notification system doesn't work.

This works when the user refreshes the page after he logs-in, because `state.auth.isAuthenticated` is `true` from the beginning.

This is because of this code:

```
if (localStorage.jwtToken) {
  // Set auth token header auth
  setAuthToken(localStorage.jwtToken);
  // Decode token and get user info and expiration
  const decoded = jwt_decode(localStorage.jwtToken);
  // Set User and is Authenticated
  store.dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));
  // Now if you reload a page, if the user has already logged-in you will still have his info in he state
  store.dispatch(clearCurrentProfile());

  // Check for expired token
  const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000;

  if (decoded.exp < currentTime) {
    store.dispatch(logoutUser());
    store.dispatch(clearCurrentProfile());
    // Redirect to login
    window.location.href = "/login";
  }
}
```

It checks if the user has already logged-in, and if he did it sets `state.auth.isAuthenticated` to `true`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is NotificationToast a library or written by youself? Do you try to use "useSelector"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

useStore is used to retrieve store. But such store access can only be used for store manipulation, like reducer replacement. When store is changed, component which access store this way is not updated.

Please use "useSelector"

`const isAuthenticated = useSelector(state => state.auth)`